# Counting the number of Enum parameters

Tags: c#, enums

I am new to enums in C#. I am passing multiple enum values as a argument to a method. Inside the method i want to know, how values do i have.

Let me Explain.

```
Class A
{
        [Flags]
        public enum days
        {
            sunday =1,
            monday =2,
            tuesday= 4
        }
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dummy(days.sunday|days.monday);
            dummy(days.sunday);

        }

public static void dummy(days Daysofweek)
        {
            if(\* Daysofweek is oly sunday*/){/*some function*/}
            else if(\* Daysofweek is sunday and monday*/){/*some other  function*/}
            Console.WriteLine(Daysofweek.ToString());

        }
}
```

'''

All i want to achieve is "if there is only one value in the argument then do something, else if there are more than one value then do some thing else".

Comment: Did you take a look at the [```HasFlag```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.8) function?

Answer (score 1):

> All i want to achieve is "if there is only one value in the argument then do something, else if there are more than one value then do some thing else".

Since `Flags` are single bits in the value and therefore powers of 2, you can use

```
uint v; // we want to see if v is a power of 2
bool f; // the result goes here 

f = (v & (v - 1)) == 0;
```

to check if the value is a power of 2, if it's not, there are more than one flag set.
See here: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2

But keep this in mind

> Note that 0 is incorrectly considered a power of 2 here.

---

```
public static void dummy(days Daysofweek)
{
    int val = (int) Daysofweek;
    bool hasMultipleFlagsSet = val != 0 && (val & (val - 1)) == 0;

    if(hasMultipleFlagsSet){/*some function*/}
    else {/*some other  function*/}
    Console.WriteLine(Daysofweek.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [HasFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.8)

```
using System;

[Flags] public enum Pets {
   None = 0,
   Dog = 1,
   Cat = 2,
   Bird = 4,
   Rabbit = 8,
   Other = 16
}

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Pets[] petsInFamilies = { Pets.None, Pets.Dog | Pets.Cat, Pets.Dog };
      int familiesWithoutPets = 0;
      int familiesWithDog = 0;

      foreach (var petsInFamily in petsInFamilies)
      {
         // Count families that have no pets.
         if (petsInFamily.Equals(Pets.None))
            familiesWithoutPets++;
         // Of families with pets, count families that have a dog.
         else if (petsInFamily.HasFlag(Pets.Dog))
            familiesWithDog++;
      }
      Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1} families in the sample have no pets.", 
                        familiesWithoutPets, petsInFamilies.Length);   
      Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1} families in the sample have a dog.", 
                        familiesWithDog, petsInFamilies.Length);   
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       1 of 3 families in the sample have no pets.
//       2 of 3 families in the sample have a dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to an integer and then count number of bits set to a 1 :

```
        public enum DAYS
        {
            sunday =1,
            monday =2,
            tuesday= 4
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DAYS days =  DAYS.sunday | DAYS.monday;
            int numDays = CountDays(days);

        }

        static int CountDays(DAYS days)
        {
            int number = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                number += ((uint)days & (1 << i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
            }
            return number;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[HasFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.8) is the way to go. Here a generic solution:

```
public static int CountFlags( Enum days )
{
    int flagsSet = 0;
    foreach( var value in Enum.GetValues( days.GetType() ) )
    {
        if( days.HasFlag( (Enum)value ) )
        {
            ++flagsSet;
        }
    }

    return flagsSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> All i want to achieve is "if there is only one value in the argument
>   then do something, else if there are more than one value then do some
>   thing else".

Assuming you don't add any "combined" named values to your enum (e.g. you don't have a `Weekend` member pre-set to `Sunday|Saturday`), you can just use [`Enum.GetName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=netframework-4.8)

It will return a non-null string for named members of the enum and `null` for any combination of more than one.